# How to create a list parameter when using Rest API

Tags: java, android, api, rest, retrofit

when constructing a method to post to via API , using REST I know how to specify int , string parameters and so forth. I would now like to know how I can do that for a list . This is what I have coded thus far

```
@POST("/api/v1/LoadAppTimeUsage/")
    void loadAppTimeUsage(
            @Query("AppTimeUsage") String app_TimeUsage,
            @Body AppTimeUsage aptu,
          // List<AppTimeUsage> getAllApps(),

            Callback<List<ResultPost>> cb
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like `@Query("apps") List<AppTimeUsage> apps` and for your example:

```
@POST("/api/v1/LoadAppTimeUsage/")
    void loadAppTimeUsage(
            @Query("AppTimeUsage") String app_TimeUsage,
            @Query("apps") List<AppTimeUsage> apps,
            @Body AppTimeUsage aptu,
            Callback<List<ResultPost>> cb
    );
```